# Replace a line in PERL with other line

Tags: string, perl, replace

I am iterating a file then there is a string for which I have to search for and from that string I have to replace a sub string with another string. Can anyone help me to solve this problem.
I tried like this.

```
while(<FH>)
{
if($_ =~ /AndroidAPIEventLogging=false/i)
{

if($& =~ s/false/True/)
{
print("Changed successfully\n");

}

}

}
```

Now it is showing that it can perform only read operations. I tried by opening the file in each possible mode.

Answer (score 2):

Match and substitute is some kind of perl anti-pattern, as you're matching (often same strings) two times, so back to your question

```
while (<FH>) {
  # everything before '\K' is not replaced (positive look behind)
  if (s/AndroidAPIEventLogging=\Kfalse/True/i) { # $_ =~ 

    print("Changed successfully\n");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that using [-i option](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html) via Perl one-liner

```
perl -i -pe 's/AndroidAPIEventLogging=false/AndroidAPIEventLogging=true/i' file1 file2...
```

As an alternative way, take a look at [Tie::File](http://perldoc.perl.org/Tie/File.html). It seems to be designed for quick in-place file edits.